checkbox selection model, dynamically update checkbox column header text
I have a checkbox selection model on a grid panel. The configuration of the CheckboxModel like this:
selMode:{
    selType:'checkboxmodel'
    checkOnly: true,
    headerText:"Select All",

    listeners:{
        select:function(this, record, index){
            if(this.selected.items.length == this.store.data.length){

                // I want to update **headerText** here 
                //when all the records's checkboxes are checked 
            }
        }
    }
}

Initially, headerText is "Select All" which is fine but when the user selects All records it should be "Unselect All".I want to update headerText dynamically.

grid listener selectionchange => checkbox.setLabel('unselectAll'). If you create a fiddle it's easier to help.


You might want to reset it, so better to use selectionchange

there is no this in the event params

try always to use getter/setter if possible (they trigger other events)

always use single quotes in ExtJS

If you work in a team try not to use this in an event, others might not know what the scope is in the event
 selModel: {
     selType: 'checkboxmodel',
     checkOnly: true,
     headerText: 'Select All',
     headerDeselectText: 'Deselect All',

     listeners: {
         selectionChange: function (selModel, record, index) {
             const columnHeader = selModel.column.getHeaderAtIndex(0),
                 deselText      = selModel.headerDeselectText,
                 selText        = selModel.headerText,
                 curText        = columnHeader.text,
                 curSelectionNo = selModel.getSelected().getCount(),
                 maxNo          = selModel.store.getCount();

             columnHeader.setText(curSelectionNo == maxNo ? deselText : selText);
         }
     }

 }




If you do want to use this... drop it directly to 'me' in the start of the funtion also so if scrope changes you still have a handle on the original scope. aka: select:function(this, record, index){ var me = this; if(this.selected.items.length == this.store.data.length){} } but as said above try only use this when the scope is obvious (like in viewcontrollers)
